# Convert list of non-quoted words into character vector in R

Tags: r

I want to provide a list of words that are unquoted and convert them into a normal string vector in R. Below is an example of what I would like to do, except for the fact that `quote` only takes 1 object at a time.

ideally the code below should return `TRUE` from identical, meaning that the words have been converted to a string vector.

```
notquotedwords<- quote(Person, Woman, Man, Camera, TV)
#Error in quote(Person, Woman, Man, Camera, TV) : 
#  5 arguments passed to 'quote' which requires 1

quotedwords<- c("Person", "Woman", "Man", "Camera", "TV")

identical(notquotedwords, quotedwords)
#ideally the output would be TRUE
```

This is a MRE, not the actual code, so yes, I understand I could just create a string vector in the first place.

Comment: Are you quoting a vector of words? ie `quote(c(Person, Woman, Man, Camera, TV))`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the arguments of a function call with `some_call[-1]`, and `match.call` will return the parent call by default, so you could do

```r
sym_to_char <- function(...){
  as.character(match.call()[-1])
}

notquotedwords <- sym_to_char(Person, Woman, Man, Camera, TV)

quotedwords <- c("Person", "Woman", "Man", "Camera", "TV")

identical(notquotedwords, quotedwords)
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

With  the rlang package, the function `ensyms` will convert its arguments to symbols.

```r
library(rlang)

sym_to_char <- function(...){
  as.character(ensyms(...))
}

notquotedwords <- sym_to_char(Person, Woman, Man, Camera, TV)

quotedwords <- c("Person", "Woman", "Man", "Camera", "TV")

identical(notquotedwords, quotedwords)
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Why do you use `sapply`? `as.character` is vectorized. hence `as.character(match.call()[-1])` should work

Comment: Thanks @Onyambu. No good reason, just that I'd used `rlang::as_string` in an earlier version which can't be used that way.

Answer (score 2):

To do this you need the `quos` and `quo_name` function from `rlang`

```
library(rlang)
notquotedwords<- quos(Person, Woman, Man, Camera, TV)
notquotedwords_char <- as.character(unlist(lapply(notquotedwords, quo_name)))
all.equal(notquotedwords_char , quotedwords)
```

Answer (score 1):

An undocumented feature of `substitute` can be used here:

```
f = function(...) as.character(substitute(...()))

identical(
  c("Person", "Woman", "Man", "Camera", "TV"),
  f(Person, Woman, Man, Camera, TV)
)
[1] TRUE
```